# Encrypted Home… Forgotten password, but I have the Passphrase

Tags: password, encryption, ecryptfs

I have forgotten the password to log in to Ubuntu (15.10). My home folder is encrypted. I *do* have the passphrase. How should I change the user password? There are some procedures [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LostPassword) but they do not mention if there is any difference if your home directory is encrypted. How to proceed?

Comment: Thanks but please note: I **do** have the passphrase so my question is quite different.

Comment: Did you read the answer? It says *"In order to get in to the encrypted home directory now, you will need one of the following: - the old login password for the account. - **the mount passphrase** used when you set up the encrypted home directory (you would have been told to write this down somewhere)."* So you can perform an administrative password change on that account (`sudo passwd username`) without knowing the old account password, and then recovering the encrypted home directory with the known encryption passphrase using the `sudo ecryptfs-recover-private /home/user` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

1. boot the pc with a live-cd or live-usb
2. mount the filesystem you lost the password from and chroot into it. from a terminal:

   ```
   cd /media
   mkdir tmp  
   sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/tmp
   sudo chroot /media/tmp /bin/bash
   ```

   `/dev/sda1` is an example. change it to where your file system is if necessary.
3. now reset the password from the user you lost the password from

   ```
   sudo passwd username
   ```
4. unmount

   ```
   sudo umount /media/tmp
   ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks  but in the scenario you describe, I wouldn't use the passphrase at all. If this would work, it would mean anyone could bypass the encryption by just mounting the drive from a live USB... that shouldn't be possible, right?

Comment: You don't need to decrypt your home folder to change your linux password. It will allow you to log in again and then you can use the passphrase to decrypt the home folder.